# Array.join not doing what it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have an array that stores all the obstacles and with my collison detection I
can use that array with an (if/else) statement so I decided to use a (.join) function, but
for some reason it only detects when the first obj it touched and completely ignores the
second obj, here is the code that im using,

```
var myArrayOne = ["#secondObs", "#firstObs" , "#thirdObs"];
var ObstacleLvlOne = $(myArrayOne.join(', '));
function handleCollisons() {
    if (collides(ObstacleLvlOne, $('#player'))) {
        $('#levelOne').stop();
        $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
    }
}

function collides(a, b) {
    var aTop = a.offset().top;
    var aLeft = a.offset().left;
    var bTop = b.offset().top;
    var bLeft = b.offset().left;

    return !(
    ((aTop + a.height()) < (bTop)) || (aTop > (bTop + b.height())) || ((aLeft + a.width()) < bLeft) || (aLeft > (bLeft + b.width())));
}
```

And here is the link. http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/63/

Comment: `join()` is almost certainly not your problem. Within `collides()`, you're calling `.top()`, `.left()`, etc. on the passed in object (`ObstacleLvlOne`) - not on the individual matched elements within that object. `.top()` and so on will only return the values for the *first* item in the list. If you want to check for collisions with any of the matched objects, you'll need to loop through them in `collides()`.

Comment: Array.join is working perfectly.

Comment: You should consider using jQuery.each() function then check the collide  method inside the body of the function

Comment: `.offset` returns the offset of the *first element* in the jQuery object only. If you want to handle each element in the jQuery object, use [`a.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Uhm thanks everyone for the ideas I tried dawez's idea but it won't work. http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/64/ ?